# Fragment lifecycles in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` generated dynamically.

**Questions:**

What is the way to catch the moment when user **slides away from the fragment** (so I can bring it into "clean", "init" state)?

or

How to catch moment when a `Fragment` is **scrolled in**?

**Problems**:

- Have checked [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating), but none of them is getting triggered  when scrolled out/in (using `ViewPager`)
- Lifecycle phases are triggered only if I scroll 2+ Fragments (those 3rd one is getting Paused/Resumed).

Comment: A ViewPager defaults to loading the Fragments on both sides of the current one (three at a time)

Comment: You can play with fragment visibility to do your stuff.

Comment: do you want to load fragment onCreate() each time viewpager slides?

Comment: I want to just refresh `Fragment` content on **each** slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a callback when a fragment gets visible to the user you can override the setUserVisibleHint method, like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //Put your 'init' logic here
    }
}
```

the variable isVisibleToUser will give the status of the visibility, so you can use the same method to handle when the fragment goes out.

Comment: Very nice! I was going for this solution - https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/. But yours is super simple and resolved my problem.

Comment: You could also use the method setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) to determine the number of fragment that will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

> [addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)
>
> void addOnPageChangeListener (ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)
>   Add a listener that will be invoked whenever the page changes or is incrementally scrolled. See ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.
>
> Components that add a listener should take care to remove it when finished. Other components that take ownership of a view may call clearOnPageChangeListeners() to remove all attached listeners.

You can implement this listener to track the movement of the fragments in the ViewPager.

There is also a method  [`setOffscreenPageLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) which Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page and it's default value is 1 and minimum value can be set to 0.